Keep original nested object type (most specific) after annotating variable
Sorry if this is a duplicate, I don't have the right terminology to look for a solution to my problem.
I'm looking for a way to retrieve the original nested types of an object, after casting it to an interface.
The example should be self-explanatory.
const exampleRoutes = {
  api: {
    products: "myProductEndpoint",
    customers: "myCustomerEndpoint",
  },
};

// The nested key of type from Pedro Figueido
// https://dev.to/pffigueiredo/typescript-utility-keyof-nested-object-2pa3
type NestedKeyOf<ObjectType extends object> = {
  [Key in keyof ObjectType & (string | number)]: ObjectType[Key] extends object
    ? `${Key}` | `${Key}.${NestedKeyOf<ObjectType[Key]>}`
    : `${Key}`;
}[keyof ObjectType & (string | number)];

// type test = "api" | "api.products" | "api.customers"
type test = NestedKeyOf<typeof exampleRoutes>;

// Perfect, now if we use an interface to typecheck our route
// we lose the concrete types of our routes
interface Routing {
  [SEGMENT: string]: Routing | number | string;
}

const exampleRoutes2: Routing = exampleRoutes;

// type test2 = string; AND NOT "api" | "api.products" | "api.customers"
type test2 = NestedKeyOf<typeof exampleRoutes2>;



• Please [edit] to make your code a [mre] without errors unrelated to your question. "The nested key of type from Pedro Figueido" is invalid TypeScript. Either write your own code that you know works, or replace it with something else that demonstrates your issue without having to come up with a deeply nested recursive conditional type.  Right now it's hard to even get started because my IDE is very unhappy about your example.

(see prev comment) • There doesn't seem to be any "casting" happening in this question. I see that you annotate exampleRoutes as Routing, but that's not considered a "cast" in TypeScript. Please [edit] to remove references to "casting".

(see prev comments) • I'm thinking once all that gets resolved, this is going to turn out to be a job for the satisfies operator, where you write const exampleRoutes2 = exampleRoutes satisfies Routing. If so I'll close this as a duplicate of a suitable question. If not, what am I missing?

This is already an MVCE, I've kept the comment because recursive types are complicated to understand and some people reading this thread might be confused, the link allows to understand the NestedKeyOf type.
I've made the other adjustments you mentioned (this is an annotation and not a casting). satisfies indeed fixed my issue, I'll wait for you to post the solution so I can select you as best answer.
Thanks.

Ok I realized I copy-pasted the wrong type indeed, it was not compiling, this is fixed.
